# preg_match variable php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to match some string in the variable.
If there is "i" or "an" in end of `$var`, return true.

```
$__var = preg_replace('/^(i|an)$/','',$var);
```

But it returns 0 (false).

Example:

```
$var = "kesehatan";
```

It should return `true`

Comment: If you only want to match at the end `$`, why do you include the subject start `^` marker?

Comment: I don't get it few minutes ago :) but not now. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `^`, otherwise you will only ever match `i` or `an`.

Comment: oh, thank you I understand. The ^ is a must if the pattern in the start of string.